# 書全經聖 - 1881 Chinese bible (what is the 2nd character?)

Tags: character-identification, characters

In collecting books, I've come across what appears to be an 1881 Chinese language bible.

Being able to read some Japanese, I'm sure of all of the characters in the title `書?經聖`, except for the 2nd one, which resembles `全`, but rather than a `人` at the top, it looks more like a `入` or `八`.

Without the ability to photograph/OCR it, I'm hoping someone could enlighten me.

**Update:** It would seem the character is correct as `全`, though finding an exact match for the phrase in Google/Baidu is not successful.

Comment: Try to reverse the characters left to right. http://webcatplus.nii.ac.jp/webcatplus/details/book/9522178.html

Comment: Brilliant! On the spine of the book, the characters are written horizontally as in the title, I was not aware that Hanzi/Kanji was sometimes read that way (vertical columns right to left, I was familiar with from Japanese, though...). Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it look like this?

[image]

This is the way how it was written in [康熙字典](http://www.zdic.net/z/15/kx/5168.htm). And the radical of `全` is `入`.

> 一作仝。会意。篆文从入,从王(玉)。盖谓交纳的玉完整无缺。本义:纯色玉

Answer (score 2):

http://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/yitia/lda/lda00283.htm

It is a variant character. 圣经全书 just means the full volume of the christian text.